# Chrome Extension callback functions and concurrency

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, concurrency

I'm learning to code Chrome Extensions and I'm curious about passing parameters into asynchronous functions and a possible concurrency issue. Let me give you an example:

```
function updateActiveTab(param1)
{
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs)
    {
        onUpdatingTab(tabs[0].id, param1);
    });
}

function onUpdatingTab(tabID, param1)
{
    console.log("Tag ID=" + tabID + ", param=" + param1);
}
```

So, lets assume that the first time my `updateActiveTab()` method is called with `param1=1` and the call to `chrome.tabs.query()` takes a while. In the meantime, while `chrome.tabs.query()` is still being processed, my `updateActiveTab()` method is called again with `param1=2`. What would happen when the first call to `chrome.tabs.query()` returns and begins processing its callback function? Will `param1` be `1` or `2`?

I'm obviously looking to pass my `param1` as 1, and 2, and so on, to its function's respective calls.

Comment: What makes you think that the variable could change?

Comment: @RobW: Idk. I'm just asking. I come from C++ development where concurrency may be an issue.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded.

Comment: @RobW: Well, not anymore: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: @RobW: And if so, how else would it run methods asynchronously?

Comment: Web Workers are still single threaded. They communicate with the main thread via events. JavaScript methods can be run asynchronously because of the "message loop" (should be a familiar term to you if you're used to C++ and IPC)..

Comment: @RobW: Oh, I see. That's a good explanation that I totally understand. I'm glad to hear this because it's a b*&^% to deal with multithreaded synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you will win. Read up on JavaScript closures to really understand what's going on here.  I'll hit the highlights so you get the idea.

The reference to param1 inside of onUpdatingTab forces param1 into a closure. The closure keeps the value of param1 alive as long as it is needed by calls to inner functions. The scenario you describe will create two different closures, one for each call to onUpdatingTab.

Here's an example adapted from JavaScript: The Good Parts that illustrates this aspect of closures.  This function takes an array of DOM nodes and adds an onclick handler that displays the ordinal of the node:

```
function add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
    var helper = function(i) {
        return function(e) { alert(i); };
    };
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
        nodes[i].onclick = helper(i);
    }
}
```

Each call to helper returns a function where the reference to "i" is bound to the closure for that helper call. Note the semantic distinction with code that doesn't use the helper, but just does this:

```
        nodes[i].onclick = function() { alert(i); }
```

Here "i" again binds to a closure, but it's the closure associated with the call to add_the_handlers, so clicking on each node displays the same value, which is the number of nodes not the ordinal.  That's the last value assigned to "i".

Comment: Here's a good explanation of JS closures: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work